# When does Ubuntu 16.04 use /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt?

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, ssl

I have some Ubuntu 16.04 server running and set up one vhost in apache2 which uses (or should use) ssl.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin myemail@mailhoster.xx
        ServerName my.domain.name.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysslsite

        <Directory /var/www/mysslsite>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ssl.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ssl.access.log combined

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I did **NOT** enable the standard sites-available/default-ssl.conf.

I am able now to browse to https://my.domain.name.de and it is asking in firefox to add some exception which is totally normal if i did not buy any certificate.

But I was wondering where it is set up that it should use the certificates in /etc/apache2/ssl/ directory. I can not find any config where it is told to use that. I all the time was thinking that it will use something from /etc/ssl folder.

Or did I maybe not activate SSL correctly?

Comment: Why do you think it is using `/etc/apache2/ssl`?

Comment: I looked on certificate details on firefox and compared with them on server. I found some other vhost with sslengine on which sets this certificates. i think that is why this vhost is working even that i never turned on sslengine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to some manuals the SSL certificate files must be placed under `/etc/apache2/ssl/`, but they can be placed in a different folder, depending on your own configuration.

To have HTTPS access to your site, you must enable the `SSLEngine` and provide a valid [SSL certificate](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html).

For this purpose you should use [OpenSSL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL) command line tool to generate your own certificate. Then you need to validate the certificate at any provider like as [COMODO](https://www.comodo.com/), [StarSSL](https://www.startssl.com/), your local DNS provider, etc. Usually they offer free certificates for few months. Regarding this way of certificate generation you may look at these guides: for [14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04) and [16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04).

Also you can use the software tool [**Let's Encrypt**](https://letsencrypt.org/). From [Let's Encrypt Getting Started](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) page:

> To enable HTTPS on your website, you need to get a certificate (a type
>   of file) from a Certificate Authority (CA). Let’s Encrypt is a CA. In
>   order to get a certificate for your website’s domain from Let’s
>   Encrypt, you have to demonstrate control over the domain. With Let’s
>   Encrypt, you do this using software that uses the ACME protocol, which
>   typically runs on your web host.

**I would suggest you to use Let's Encrypt, at this stage. So let's begin.**

**1st** - install Let's Encrypt:

```
sudo apt install python-letsencrypt-apache
```

**2nd** - generate the certificate. To generate SSL certificate compatible with Apache just type: `letsencrypt --apache`. This command will start interactive dialogue (where you must fill your site's personal data) and will generate `HTTPS.conf` file based on your existing `HTTP.conf` file.

You can use and some additional parameters, for example `letsencrypt --apache certonly` will do the same as above but will not generate `HTTPS.conf` file.

Also you can put all necessary parameters to avoid the dialogue. According to the information provided in the question our command should looks like:

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --email myemail@mailhoster.xx -d my.domain.name.de
```

Let's assume you choose the last approach. The command will generate all necessary certificate files and they will be placed in the folder `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/my.domain.name.de/`. Also these files will be sym-linked into the folder `/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.name.de/`. These symlinks will be updated automatically in the future, so we will use them.

**3rd** -  configure (manually) your HTTPS VirtualHost. According to the above the configuration file should looks like:

```xml
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

       ServerAdmin myemail@mailhoster.xx
       ServerName my.domain.name.de
       DocumentRoot /var/www/mysslsite           

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.name.de/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.name.de/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.name.de/chain.pem

        <Directory /var/www/mysslsite>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ssl.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ssl.access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**4th** - `a2ensite` the new VirtualHost, just in case `a2enmod ssl` and restart Apache. That's it. I hope now you will have HTTPS access to your site.

**5th** - renew your certificate into the future. For this purpose you can edit root's [Crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/869557/566421) and add a job which will try to `letsencrypt renew` the certificates, every Sunday at 3:00 AM for example. Type `sudo crontab -e` and add this line at the bottom:

```
0 3 * * 0 /usr/bin/letsencrypt renew >> /var/log/letsencrypt-renew.log 2>&1
```

---

Notes:

- `letsencrypt` / `python-letsencrypt-apache` is available for Ubuntu 16.04 and above, for previous versions there is `certbot` which is almost the same - from [Ubuntu Manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/letsencrypt.1.html).
- If you have few VirtualHosts you can use this syntax to generate their certificates (all together):

  ```
  sudo letsencrypt --apache certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --email myemail@mailhoster.xx -d my.domain.name-1.de -d my.domain.name-2.de -d my.domain.name-3.de
  ```
- [certbot.eff.org](https://certbot.eff.org/) - Automatically enable HTTPS on your website with EFF's Certbot, deploying Let's Encrypt certificates.
- **The above answer is based on [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/893406/566421), where more details about the Apache's VH configuration are provided.**

---

Read here how and why you should updatete your `letsecrypt`/`certbot` until February 13th, 2019: [Failed to upgrade certbot on Ubuntu Bionic](https://askubuntu.com/q/1113499/566421)