# UBuntu SSL install apache

Tags: 14.04, apache2, ssl, mod-ssl

My doman provider gaves me two files:-

1. `domain.com_ssl_certificate.cer`
2. `-.domian.com_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer`

What should I do in order to activated SSL on my domain?

Comment: You should propably just ask the Provider.

Comment: are you sure i need to speak with  my provider ? i hosted another cloud server for my subdomain.

Comment: There is a lot of manuals how to enable HTTPSecure (SSL/TLS) connection for Apache2. For example please read the answers of these questions: (1) [How do you set up SSL certificates for additional ports in Apache?](https://askubuntu.com/q/950815/566421) Just ignore the port  changing part within the answers.; (2) [When does Ubuntu 16.04 use /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/900400/566421); (3) [How to disable SSLv3 and Weak Ciphers](https://askubuntu.com/q/903199/566421).