# Ubuntu 16.04 apache tls settings wont affect

Tags: apache2, ssl, tls

My setup is fresh Ubuntu 16.04 server installation with Apache 2.4.18 and Openssl 1.0.2g. I have made ssl configs to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf` and checked that there are no same configs in vhost -files etc. Still no matter what I do I cant get no change on ssllabs.com raport. I tried even comment all SSLProtocol and SSLciphersuite lines but still no change. Yes I have restarted the server after the changes.

What am I missing?

Comment: mmm.. thats the file i referred on my post(?) There I have been working with the configs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I found it. While letting the certbot (https://certbot.eff.org/) to modify the virtualhost -files it added this line at the end:

**Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf**

So apparently configs in this file will override the ones in /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf.

Comment: In 16.04 and newer you can use `letsencrypt`, that is a Certbot's flavour from the Ubuntu's repository - you don't need additional PPA - as it is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900400/when-does-ubuntu-16-04-use-etc-apache2-ssl-apache-crt/900433#900433).