# How to check SSL is enabled for Apache2 or Not

Tags: 14.04, networking, apache2, apache2.4

Twiki is running locally on my web server apache2. I used `a2enmod ssl` to enable SSL (Secure Socket Layer). Now i want to see SSL is enabled or not ? Or i need more configurations to achieve task (i-e) to enable SSL.

Comment: Are you using 14.04? If not, please use the appropriate tag for the version you're using. If you're using 14.04, note that 14.04 is no longer supported here but support is available **commercially** from Canonical. See https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-14-04-esm-support for details.

Comment: I think this topic could be interesting for you, there is described how to generate and apply free SSL/TLS certificate: https://askubuntu.com/q/900400/566421

Answer (score 4):

In case you haven't already done so, do a:

```
service apache2 restart
```

after the `a2enmod ssl` you just did.

Then, you use the following command to test SSL:

```
curl -vk https://localhost/ -o /dev/null
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать в Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Please put the commands users have to execute first also as the first command they have to execute...  **;-)**